# Power shell script Get-ADGroup member and owner

Tags: active-directory, powershell, shell-scripting

I'm having some problems with my powershell script to get ADGroups from our AD. I want the information about what the group name, description of the group, members in the groups and the owner of the group.

I have this script written allready

```
$GruppeMedlemmer = @()
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -properties * -SearchBase "OU=butikk,OU=Grupper,OU=Costumer,DC=OO,DC=NN"
foreach ($g in $Groups) {
$members = $g | Get-ADGroupMember 
     foreach ($m in $members) {
       $Info = New-Object psObject 
       $Info | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupName" -Value $g.Name
       $Info | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $g.description
  $Info | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member of" -Value $g.MemberOf
       $Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member" -Value $m.name    
       $GruppeMedlemmer+= $Info
     }
}
$GruppeMedlemmer | Sort-Object GroupName | Export-CSV C:\data\groupdist.csv -notype -Encoding unicode
```

This script gives me the group names, description and members of the group, but I'm not sure what to add to get the group owner.

Can I add a new line "managedby" -Value $m.name ? I must be writing something wrong, because when I try to add new line to get managedby it only fails.

Can somebody help me with the right way to implement this in my script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add a new line "managedby" -Value $m.name ?

`ManagedBy` is a property of [Get-ADGroup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12079.active-directory-get-adgroup-default-and-extended-properties.aspx) so in your script you have to use `$g.ManagedBy`

```
$Info | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ManagedBy" -Value $g.ManagedBy
```

BTW It would help to know which PowerShell version you use.